# How to fix "TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list"

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have a `TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list`. I have created the method `create_index`, and I want this function to search through a field name in mongodb.

I have tried adding `.sort('recipe', pymongo.ASCENDING)` but this doesn't work. I still get the same error on this line:

```
total = mongo.db.recipe.create_index({'$text': {'$search': db_query }})
```

My search method code:

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    """Route for full text search bar"""
    page_limit = 6 #Logic for pagination
    current_page = int(request.args.get('current_page', 1))
    db_query = request.args['db_query']
    total = mongo.db.recipe.create_index({'$text': {'$search': db_query }})
    t_total = len([x for x in total])
    pages = range(1, int(math.ceil(t_total / page_limit)) + 1)
    results = mongo.db.recipe.find({'$text': {'$search': db_query }}).sort('_id', pymongo.ASCENDING).skip((current_page - 1)*page_limit).limit(page_limit)
    return render_template('search.html', results=results, pages=pages, current_page=current_page, db_query=db_query)
```

I expect the search function to search through my database eg on the site if I type 'rice' it should search for a rice receip instead I get "TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list". Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

try wrapping it in a list, for example:

`db.recipe.create_index( [('field_here', pymongo.ASCENDING)] )`

Answer (score 1):

mydoc = records.find().sort([('_id', pymongo.ASCENDING), ('age',pymongo.DESCENDING)])
for x in mydoc:
print(x)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

While you press the search key you wanna see the selected word. You
should try get API over there so when you search for any key word you can call the particular id in the database and then search for the key word.

```
{
    receip.find({keyword: request.query.keyword, active: true})
}
```